# Getting 400 Bad Request response when uploading large file directly to amazon s3 bucket

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I've followed this tutorial: https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2013/direct-upload-to-s3-with-a-little-help-from-jquery/

Everything works fine except when I try to upload large files. I also enabled file chunking and set the max file size for a chunk to 5mb. Yet the error still persists, randomly appears whenever I try to upload a file that's about 70mb. Sometimes it even works but most of the time it doesn't.

Here's the response I'm getting:

```
Remote Address:54.231.17.48:80
Request URL:http://s3.amazonaws.com/.../
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
```

response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:ETag, x-amz-meta-custom-header
Access-Control-Max-Age:30000
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Mon, 12 Oct 2015 14:07:00 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-...
x-amz-request-id:...
```

Response body:

```
<Error>
            <Code>
                RequestTimeout
            </Code>
            <Message>
                Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
            </Message>
            <RequestId>
                7699FD31BA7905C6
            </RequestId>
            <HostId>
                ...
            </HostId>
        </Error>
```

How can I make this work? It works some of the time but not all of the time.

Comment: Is there anything in the response *body*?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've added the response body as well.